# SVN Achitecture - synching/exporting files to remote servers

Tags: svn

I'm about to setup an SVN server and I'll need to push out code to a few remote servers of various flavors (Windows 2008 and Linux (Apache and Tomcat) ).

What is the best approach to push out code? Rsynch between servers? SFTP? Invoking SVN export from the remote server? I'm thinking a post-commit action/event on each repository to launch this. A multi-plaform solution would be key.

**Edit #1**
Just learned that svn export will not synch, it will leave deleted files intact on the remote server...

**Edit #2**

- I have to take into account of many repositories to be pushed (or pulled) to these servers.
- These involved PHP or ASP.Net projects (sites/applications)

**Solution**

- Installed Hudson on other servers
- checkout source code to specific locations on our web servers
- create a job for a specific project that changes directory to working copy and call svn up
- post-commit hook that does a wget on job URL - hudson/job/name_of_job/build?delay=0sec

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A post-commit hook which invokes `svn update` on each remote system, with a working copy on each of those systems, is one route you can go (and common enough to be a [FAQ entry](http://subversion.apache.org/faq.html#website-auto-update)).

You may also want to look into a continuous integration server, especially if the items you need to push out are applications which must be compiled and deployed (as is probably the case with Tomcat). In this case, rather than pushing from the Subversion server, your CI server will poll to check for changes and pull the update(s), then run your compile/test/deploy scripts and report on the results.

Comment: Do I need to install the CI server on all machines? Or does it run from a single spot? Wouldn't the CI server be calling an update on the individual repositories anyways? How would it differ from having a php, .net and .jsp page calling the svn update and me calling that page? What other features would a CI give us? A log of the operations that occured?

Comment: It depends on how the CI system you choose works, but you probably will need to install it on all machines (or set up network shares to move things around). What exactly the CI does will depend upon how your code needs to be deployed - J2EE apps, it'll compile, run unit tests and deploy into Tomcat, for example (you can/should pre-compile your ASP.NET apps too). If all of your code runs from a basic working copy, then all you *need* is a simple svn up (in theory). Having a web page on your server which can invoke a system command and modify running code sounds like a major security risk to me.

Comment: I can't invoke the svn up from PHP (access denied and post-research, agree with you on how insecure it is) so, I'll have to install the CI server and attempt it from that angle. So, the theory is that my post commit calls a URL from Hudson, which in turns executes the svn up? Shares are not an option for us. Thanks!

Comment: No, Hudson will be polling the repository to check for changes, and when a change is detected it will perform whatever processing you've defined for it. No post-commit hook necessary. I haven't used Hudson, so I can't speculate on the details of implementation/configuration.

Comment: I decided to forge ahead and install Hudson...ATM, I'm running Hudson on a remote server and created a job that simply changes directory (where I did my checkout) and does svn update. In my post-commit, I do a simple wget equivalent on the URL of the job server/job/name_of_job/build?delay=0sec and it seems to be working as intended. Plus, It keeps track of the builds and so forth. IIRC, Hudson can only poll at minute intervals. For our webstuff (PHP/.Net), as these are development, that may be too long of an interval... FWIW...

Comment: 1 minute seems a bit short, IMHO. I use CCNet and have it poll on a 5-minute interval, and it's plenty. If you're doing this because it's the only way to test your code, then you should have a way to test your application on your workstation *before* committing the changes to the repository. Otherwise you'll end up with hundreds of commits (and deploys) which are nothing more than "fixed typo in page title" and "corrected code so it compiles properly."

Comment: unfortunately, our workstations are locked and this is the only way we have to test code. I doubt that I'll be able to change our IT policies :)

Comment: When policy prevents work being done properly and efficiently, the policy must be fixed. A degree of control over workstations needs to be maintained, but not at the expense of productivity. Demonstrate (with metrics) the inefficiencies & performance penalty that your development team is paying as a result of this policy, and you may get things changed. That being said, even with your workstations "locked", there *should* be ways to get the software you need up and running within the boundaries that exist.

Answer (score -1):

[svnsync](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.reposadmin.maint.html#svn.reposadmin.maint.tk.svnsync).

It works very well, just be careful about putting it in both post-commit and post-revprop-change hooks as it'll get called twice for most commits. You'll also want to make the remote servers read-only to all but the svnsync user.

You can also make these repos read-only but push writers back to the master repo automatically, so the remote can be used as caches. Svnsync is also excellent for making continuous backups.

The [repository replication](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.reposadmin.maint.html#svn.reposadmin.maint.replication) section of the redbook says all you need to know.

Comment: does it matter that I have the .svn folders? The remote server is the web server that will be serving the code. Plus, I'm just looking at getting the tip of the repository and not necessarily need all the history and such...

Comment: svnsync is for creating a mirror of the repository, not for distributing versioned artifacts to other locations.

Comment: shame, you should have said that you only wanted the head revision in the original question.